# replace broken image by placeholder image

Tags: jquery, image, hide

I have to hide broken images, images that have empty source or faulty source link and replace with a placeholder image for doctor's profile page. What I have works fine in chrome, but in IE and FF, the broken image gets hidden but doesn't get replaced by the placeholder image? I am not seeing why??

```
$(function() { 
    $("img.PhysicianImage").one("load", function() { 
        $(this).show(); 
    }).each(function() { 
        if (this.complete) $(this).load(); 
    }).error(function () {   
        $(this).unbind("error").attr("src", "http://mysite/Physician%20Images/no_photo.jpg"); 
    }).hide(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `.one()` unbinds after the first invocation, so that might be your problem.

along with `this.complete` you can check if it has `this.naturalWidth` if that's 0 or undefined the image hasn't loaded yet, but when it does that gets updated with the image's dimensions